# What application can read and write data to Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, data-entry

I have been tasked with creating an application or using an existing one (Access, Excel, Power Apps) that allows users to read Snowflake data and also allow update, insert and delete operations. I am pretty sure Excel, Access and PowerApps are read only. PowerApps would also run 10 bucks a month for an app that currently only needs to be used once a quarter.

I was hoping I could used ODBC, but it looks like that only reads, no writeback. I do have the ability to use a SQL server as a middle man. I thought I would use ADF to mirror the data being modified with truncate and loads to Snowflake. But if I could skip that link in the chain it would be preferable.

Thoughts?

Comment: so many ways. You can use jdbc. You can write files to S3 and read in snowflake using stage...

Comment: So JDBC to read the data from Snowflake, then write edits, inserts and I guess a flag on a record ID to a file in S3. Then Snowflake Stage will process the Edits, Inserts and deletes. That doesn't seem efficient and has several points of failure. Maybe I should just have the client install DBeaver. I'll google jdbc for some articles. Thanks.

Comment: Snowflake is an analytical database but you seem to be trying to use it as the datastore for an application, a use case it was never designed to support. Can you explain in more detail what you are trying to do and/or why you are using Snowflake rather than a more use-appropriate DB for what you appear to be trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of tools that can help you and business users read and write back to Snowflake. Many users then use [Streams and Tasks](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-pipelines-intro.html) on the table that is updated to automate further processing on Snowflake.

Some examples:

1. [Open-source Excelerator](https://github.com/Snowflake-Labs/Excelerator) - Excel plug-in to write to Snowflake
2. [Sigma Computing](https://help.sigmacomputing.com/hc/en-us/articles/360037430473-Set-Up-Write-Access) - a cloud-native, serverless Excel / BI tool

Comment: Excelerator worked really well once I got used to how to update rows where there were autogenerated columns.